# How to check if file is closed or not

Tags: python, python-2.7

I opened a temporary file with the following code in Python:

```
p=subprocess.Popen(tempFileName,shell=True)

 processId=p.pidcode
```

I want to remove that temporary file, when that file is closed.
I wanted to remove the file with the PiD of opening process, but the problem is even when I close that file pid still exists.

```
 p=subprocess.Popen(tempFileName,shell=True)
 processId=p.pid
```

Are there any other ways to remove that temporary file?

Comment: `Popen` doesn't open a temporary file. It runs an external program and provides references to its standard input/output/error. Even so, the value of the `pid` attribute isn't going to change simply because the process that used to use that ID has completed.

Comment: Erm, `subrocess.Popen` doesn't open a file - check the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor)

Answer (score 6):

Why not use [tempfile](http://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html)? It should be portable and can remove files without you bothering with it.